# How to implement a default routing behaviour with Lumen or Slim framework

Tags: php, url-routing, slim, lumen, psr-4

I'm looking into using Lumen or possibly Slim for a project and wondered whether it was possible to autoload controllers based on directory structure rather than having to register all routes.

This is how I would like the autoloading to work .

**Example Directory/class structure:**

```
 /app/Http/Controllers/
    Foo/
        BarController.php        # App\Http\Controllers\Foo\BarController
```

If the route were

`example.com/foo/bar` == `App\Http\Controllers\Foo\BarController::index()`

`example.com/foo/bar/add` ==  `App\Http\Controllers\Foo\BarController::add()`

Registered routes should take priority over the autoloaded classes.

I have found a way of doing this based on Opencart's routing method. 
They have 1145 different public methods over 396 controllers which are all called without explicitly stating the controller & method. 
Here is my attempt.

.htaccess

`RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]`

app/Http/routes.php

```
$route = array_shift($_GET);
$method_name = '';

$parts = explode('/', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\/]/', '', (string)$route));

while ($parts) {

    $class = '\App\Http\Controllers\\' . implode('\\', $parts);

    if (class_exists($class)){
        $app->match($route, $class . '@' . method_exists($class, $method_name) ? $method_name : 'index');
        break;
    } else {
        $method_name = array_pop($parts);
    }
}
```

If a route is required which differs from the default the Opencart then use `.htaccess RewriteRule` or a `response->redirect` to route to an alternative controller.

I would to use their approach but state my route overrides in 
`app/Http/routes.php`. like so

```
// route overrides 
$app->get('/', 'common/home@index');
$app->get('/home', 'common/home@index');
```

Am I right in thinking this would make the application run faster as it wouldn't have to search all registered routes for a match ?

Is there a better way of performing this automatic routing process ?

Comment: What you are trying to do wouldn't let your app work faster or slower, for some reason people are focusing on wrong things in order to optimize. However, your idea defeats the purpose of routing completely. You **want** to define a route and you **want** to explicitly state what is going to handle it. If you're trying to "automate" route handlers, then you're implementing hidden magic. Ultimately, a route will get matched against a handler (controller / function). It's just infinitely better to explicitly state what handles it. You gain nothing from this type of automation except trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could make this work with a combination of [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) and Slim 3's support for [defining routes with controller methods instead of closures](http://juliangut.com/blog/slim-controller).

The basic strategy would be as follows:

1. Search through each of your controller classes (using `glob` or an autoloader);
2. For each class, call `ReflectionClass::getMethods`, using the `ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC` filter so you only get the public methods for the class;
3. Get the class name using `ReflectionClass::getName` and namespace (if necessary) using `ReflectionClass::getNamespaceName`;
4. Build your route signature from the namespace, class name, and method name, perhaps using a slugification library like https://github.com/cocur/slugify;
5. Generate the corresponding route `$app->get($route_signature, "$class_name:$method_name")`.

This is an interesting idea, although you need to be extremely careful that this doesn't accidentally expose any methods that you don't want directly accessible to the client.  A few other notes:

- Reflection is very slow so you will probably want to implement this as more of a build step, caching the generated routes rather than regenerating them on the fly with each request.
- You may need some additional naming convention to distinguish HTTP verbs.  For example, beginning all method names that correspond to `GET` routes with `get`.  So you might have `\Foo\BarController::getAdd`, `\Foo\BarController::postAdd`, etc.
- Constructing parameterized routes (`/bar/add/{id}`) will be a little more work, as you will probably want to extract the corresponding method arguments using `ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getParameters`.  Again, you would need to decide on some convention as to how the routes should be constructed based on these parameters.